# Is there a way to define input context for a Google Action with the Actions SDK?

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home

In the DialogFlow console, you can set an input and output context for an intent.

I would like to have the same functionality using the Actions SDK. 
Since I can set the context in my fullfilment webhook in the code, the output SDK is covered.
However, how do I set the input context for an intent to only trigger if that context was fetched?

I could not find this in the documentation examples.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can in the same way, which is part of why they added Dialogflow.

Although as part of your response you can indicate the [ExpectedInput](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/rest/Shared.Types/AppResponse#ExpectedInput) for the next Intent, the documentation for the [ExpectedIntent](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/rest/Shared.Types/AppResponse#ExpectedIntent) makes it clear that your Intents are only used for speech biasing - you'll always get the built-in TEXT Intent.

In fact, [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/rest/Shared.Types/AppRequest#Input) says that you'll only get custom Intents for the initial call - later Intents are always triggered with a built-in one.

**Update**: One thing you *can* do is to include information in the response that will be sent back to you in the next request.

If you're using the [JavaScript SDK](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/nodejs/ActionsSdkApp#ask), this is done with the second parameter to `ask()` and is available via the `getDialogState()` function.

If you're sending back JSON, this is done using the `conversationToken` attribute and is available in `conversation.conversationToken` in the request object you're sent the next round.